# Why does this PowerShell script output the words "Coloring console" when called from a PHP script?

Tags: php, powershell, output

I have a Windows PowerShell script `test.ps1` that is called by a PHP script using `shell_exec`.

For whatever reason, the output from the script always begins with this: "Coloring console". Even when `test.ps1` is absolutely blank, it returns just that phrase. Also, every other task/output is correct, with the exception of this one issue.

I have moved to the script around to several directories in the process of troubleshooting, but it makes no difference. Also, I have done this (for all 4 combinations):

```
sc $Profile.AllUsersCurrentHost $null
```

just in case there is some code in the profile, muddling up the environment.

The PHP code is like this:

```
$scr = "PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\\TEMP\\test.ps1";
$output = shell_exec( $scr );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

Why does this blank PowerShell script produce the output: "Coloring console", thereby polluting my expected return output?

Comment: Did you try launching powershell with the `-NoProfile` switch?

Comment: @arco444. Thanks for dropping by, and for your suggestion. I actually did try your suggestion of `-NoProfile` but it made no difference. However, I want to report that further along during the day, when I went back to that script, I just realized that THE PROBLEM WAS GONE! I hadn't changed anything else, didn't restart computer, but the "Coloring console" just wasn't there anymore. So, problem is solved but question is still alive ;)